# Postgres hstore check if a key exists and does not match value

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I have a hstore field in an audit table that stores all the fields that have changed as a result of an operation.

On inserts, the key, `updated_by` in `changed_fields` is NULL and on system updates it is set to `system`. I would like to return all rows where either the key is not defined or the key is not `system` but I am lost as to how to do this.

So far I have tried

```
select changed_fields -> 'updated_by' 
from audit.logged_actions 
where (changed_fields -> 'updated_by' != 'system' 
       or defined(changed_fields, 'updated_by') = false) 
order by event_id desc
```

But that doesn't work and I am not quite sure why. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Answer (score 12):

The usage of `defined()` in the documentation:

> does hstore contain non-NULL value for key?

In addition to a NULL value for an existing key, it returns `FALSE` also when the key does not exist.

To keep it clean, you might want to use the `exist()` function instead:

```
SELECT exist('"bla" => 1234', 'bloo');
 exist 
───────
 f
```

So your query would look like

```
SELECT changed_fields -> 'updated_by' 
  FROM audit.logged_actions 
 WHERE changed_fields -> 'updated_by' <> 'system' 
       OR NOT exist(changed_fields, 'updated_by')
 ORDER by event_id desc;
```

**Notes:**

- never test logical values using the equality operator (unless you can be *really* sure the value cannot be NULL).  You can directly use the value if it is guaranteed to not be NULL (like in my query), or use the [`IS` operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html).
- In the current form, the query is checking a simple 'OR' - from your wording it is not quite clear what should happen when both conditions are true.

Comment: Can't you use `OR changed_fields->'updated_by' IS NULL` instead? This would work both for a defined key that's null, and for an undefined key; whereas your `EXIST` method would only work for an undefined key, but give you the wrong answer if you have:  `'"updated_by" => NULL'` in your hstore.  IE, try: `select exist('"bloo" => NULL', 'bloo');` and you will get `t` even though it's `NULL` and you probably want `f`

Comment: @nzifnab Six years later I am not totally sure how the original question used 'defined', but to me it sounds `exist()` gave the needed answer.  If your use case differs (e.g. you want to distinguish between the cases you mention), I think you can use your proposed version.